# how to save information in input tags using cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have a table on web page. 
I wanna save informaton in input's fields using cookie.   i. e. I want to reopen my web page and see data from last opening web page.

**HTML**

```
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="table-visual-features">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Visual Feature</th>
                                <th>Step</th>
                                <th>Output</th>
                                <th>Data Feature</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>x</td> 
                                <td><select><option>first</option></select></td>
                                <td><select><option>output</option></select></td>
                                <td><input name="data-feature_x"  id="value0" class = "feature-execution"/></td>
                           </tr>

                            <tr><td>x</td> 
                                <td><select><option>second</option></select></td>
                                <td><select><option>output</option></select></td>
                                <td><input name="data-feature_x"  id="value1" class = "feature-execution"/></td>
                           </tr>



                            <tr><td>x</td> 
                                <td><select><option>third</option></select></td>
                                <td><select><option>output</option></select></td>
                                <td><input name="data-feature_x"  id="value2" class = "feature-execution"/></td>
                           </tr>



                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to set and retrieve the contents of cookies.

Using `$.cookie.json = true` allows you to store JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
var getValue = function(id){
  return document.querySelector('#'+id).value;
};

var saveCookie = function(){
  document.cookie = '';
  document.cookie += 'a='+getValue('value0');
  document.cookie += 'b='+getValue('value1');
  document.cookie += 'c='+getValue('value2');
};
```

**Demo:**

http://jsbin.com/IZULuRE/4/edit

Of course, edit code for your usage :), its only demo.

Comment: I do not understand, what you are mining...